# Memory counter - Collision Detection Project

Tags: c++, memory, count, collision-detection

I thought I would ask the experts - see if you can help me :o)
My son has written C++ code for Collision Detection using Brute Force and Octree algorithms.

He has used Debug etc - and to collect stats on mem usage he has used windows & task manager - which have given him all the end results he has needed so far. The results are not yet as they were expect to be (that Octree would use more memory overall).

His tutor has suggested he checks memory once each is "initialised" and then plot at points through the test.

He was pointed in the direction of Valgrind .... but it looked uite complicated and becaus ehe has autism, he is worried that it might affect his programmes :o)

Anyone suggest a simple way to grab the information on Memory if not also Frame Rate and CPU usage???

Any help gratefully received, as I know *nothing* so can't help him at all, except for typing this on here - as it's "social" environment he can't deal with it.

Thanks
Rosalyn

Comment: +1 for putting the effort in to help. Can't you help him convert his initial fear of tools (that might 'affect his program') into the _challenge_ of understanding exactly how valgrind works, and predicting the outcome? With my limited understanding of autism, this should be the ideal type of thing for him to focus and thrive on. Besides, it would give him an advantage in the profession of programming

Comment: Oh, by the way: I shouldn't think valgrind is complicated, when one is implementing collision detection. Valgrind is a tool that is actually quite simple in concept, it's strength is bruteforce analysis that humans could never match. (_The implementation of valgrind is probably complex; but again the concept of instrumenting binaries isn't; Once you approach things on the right level of abstraction, the 'magic' and 'uncertainties' might become tractable_)

Comment: This is his final report and due in by the end of next week - I thinkhe is just concerned it might make things harder ... trouble is his testing didn't PROVE Octree needs mega more memory to run - so he's currently increasing the objects tested. His tutor suggested the discover MEM used once data loaded and see how it increases .... just not sure how to do it - quickly and easily - maybe look at Valgrind - he has a game to build next so it could come in very useful. Many thanks Sehe

Answer (score 2):

**For the memory leaks**:

If you're on Windows, Visual C++ by Microsoft (the Express version is [free](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP)) has a nice tool for debugging and is easy to setup with instructions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx); otherwise if you're on Linux, Valgrind is one of the standards. I have used the Visual C++ tool often and it's a nice verification that you have no memory leaks. Also, you can use it to enabled your programs to break on allocation numbers that you get from the memory leak log so it quickly points you to when and where the memory is getting assigned that leaks. Again, it's easy to implement (just a few header files and then a single function call where you want to dump the leaks at).

I have found the best way to implement the VC++ tool is to make the call to dump the memory leaks to the output window right before main returns a value. That way, you can catch the leaks of absolutely everything in your program. This works very well and I have used it for some advanced software.

**For the framerate and CPU usage**:

I usually use my own tools for benchmarking since they're not difficult to code once you learn the functions to call; this would usually require OS API calls, but I think Boost has that available and is cross-platform. There might be other tools out there that can track the process in the OS to get benchmarking data as well, but I'm not certain if they would be free or not.

Comment: Hi Zach, thank you for your answer. He has used Visual Studio 2008 express and his OS is W7.  I had had him read the answer, but he doesn't seem to understand it... I have asked hi to go and look on the debug tool and see what he can find. Might get back to you if that's OK. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If the program your son wrote is using more memory than expected is because in some places is asking for memory an not releasing it. The memory that is used and lost during the execution is called a memory leak. In other words, memory leaks are the reason the application is using more memory than expected and also the reason why his tutor told hit to check with Valgrind. Valgrind is a very known tool to check memory leaks, every time memory is requested Valgrind keeps track of it and if an error happens, it will tell you when the memory was allocated and the reason for the error.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Alex - his tutor recommended NOT employing Valgrind at this late stage in his disseration project - he suggested using an INITIALISE command --- not sure how that works - but my son is going to see if he can understand that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running under a windows system.  This isn't a programming solution, and you may have already tried it (so feel free to ignore), but if not, you should take a look at performance monitor (it's one of the tools that ships with windows).  It'll let you track all sorts of useful stats about individual proceses and the system as a whole (cpu/commit size etc).  It plots the results for you as a graph as the program is running and you can save the results off for future viewing.

On Windows 7, you get to it from here:

`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Performance Information and Tools\Advanced Tools`

Then Open Performance Monitor.

For older versions of windows, it used to be one of the administrative tools options.

Comment: Hi Forsvarir Yes, we he is using W7 - he has now found the Perf Mon - he willhave a look at it tomorrow after UNI and see if it is helpful - THANKS :o)

Comment: Hi there - my son's tutor said he has, so far, managed to automate the collection of the data - and suggested NOW trying the INITIALISE command???  But my son isnt sure HOW to do that .... we did look at the Perf Mon - it was helpful. Thank you

Comment: @asdtrainer:  I'm not sure what the `INITIALISE` command would refer to, or how you'd use it.  Hopefully the two of you will figure it out / can get more information from the tutor.  Good luck!